# Plan curve with zero area has at least two points of zero curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Let $\alpha=(x,y)$ be a smooth closed plan curve defined on $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$. We can define the oriented area of $\alpha$ by $A=\int_{a}^{b} x(s)y'(s)ds$. So, if A=0 then there exists $t_1 \neq t_2 \in [a,b] $ such that $k(t_1)=k(t_s)=0.$ Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

An idea of counterexample is found on every Mac keyboard:

## ⌘

Imagine going along this curve, turning always to the left. The four loops at corners are traced counterclockwise, contributing positive area. The central part is traced clockwise, contributing negative area. It becomes clear that adjusting the sizes, one can achieve total area zero.

Here is a [larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xSPF.png), with zero area and nonvanishing curvature. It can be described in complex coordinates as 
$$\alpha(t)=\sqrt{3}e^{-it}+e^{3it} \tag1$$ 
The oriented area bounded by parametric curve $t\mapsto \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} c_ne^{int}$ is equal to $\pi \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} n|c_n|^2$, which is zero for the curve (1).
In real coordinates,
$$x(t)=\sqrt{3}\cos t +\cos 3t,\quad  y(t)=-\sqrt{3}\sin t+\sin 3t  $$